# Flask decorators to limit access to certain route

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

How can I limit access to a route by using custom decorators? Or is there a better and simple way to this?

Below is the code to reset forget password:

```
@auth.route('/reset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset_verify():
    if not current_user.is_anonymous():
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = PasswordResetVerifyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('auth.password_reset', uid=form.uid.data))
    return render_template('auth/reset.html', form=form)
```

I don't want others to access this route until they have verified the above route. Since you can change others password by doing /reset/123456789

```
@auth.route('/reset/<uid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset(uid):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous():
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    form = PasswordResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(uid=uid).first()
        if user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        if user.reset_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Your password has been updated.')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('auth/reset.html', form=form)
```

How can I write my custom decorator so that guests have to no permissions to get in to password_rest route. In another word, password_rest route is an one time access to that verify  only. Or is there a way that I can combine password_rest into password_rest_verify?

Comment: What flask libraries are you using here? I know `flask.ext.login` has a really simple decorator for this.

Comment: You shouldn't include the `<uid>` in the route.  I assume you know the user is logged in and can therefor retrieve their `uid` from the session object.  After they validate their password, you set an additional session value `password_reset_verified = True` or similar, then on the `password_reset` function you check that it is set, reset their password, and clear the value from the session.  In fact I see you are accessing `current_user` so you can just get the `uid` from there.  **Never trust users**.

Comment: This is poor security, as stated by @sberry you would never actually use a uid to reset a password...Assign a unique token, send the email and ask the user to confirm through the email (of course this means that emails are also verified during registration).

Comment: @sberry No, logged in user can never access password rest page, there's another route to change password for logged in users. I retrieve their uid from previous PasswordResetVerifyForm from and get the uid value pass to password_reset(uid) for user query.

Comment: @petkostas Yes, I do realize that this is poor security. I do not have the flask-email set up, I want user to be able reset their password at the site instead going to email and click on a link. Maybe I'll generate an unique token to replace <uid>

Comment: @Ricek: I see, I misread your question and thought this was for resetting the password of the logged in user.  So I would suggest, instead, you create a new class (like PasswordChangingUser) by implementing the User interface described here: https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#your-user-class.  Then when they verify on the first page, you set their user to an instance of that type, then verify that their user is of that type on the second page, retrieve their uid from that instance, and let them reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used `itsdangerous` to generates token

`generate_reset_token` method generates a token with a default validity of time. 
`reset_password` function checks that the id from the token matches the verified user.